# Making two Docker containers work together

Tags: docker

I am seeking advices on how to dockerize my application. This is how the application works :
There is a website that is responsible to help the user create inputs for an executable. The inputs are two images, one uploaded by the user and one where the user draw something on his uploaded image. The website uses Python/Django and Apache2. When done, the website writes the two images on the server, stores them in a mysql database and calls an executable that uses the two images as input. The executable uses OpenCV 3.1 and can be called like that :

```
./my_executable.sh ./path_to_image1.jpg ./path_to_image2.jpg ./path_where_to_save_output.jpg
```

The executable then writes the output image on the server in the same location as the two other input images, and the website displays the result.

For now, a Docker-Compose orchestrates two containers, one with the official mysql image (I actually have no issue with this container, it works fine as I just need to tell Django where to find the database using the service name), and one I created with all Python/Django/Apache2/OpenCV3.1 dependencies. Meaning the website and the executable run in the same container. From what I understand of Docker, the website and the executable should run in separate containers. But I just can't figure out how can a container tell another container to execute something.

I can create an image i_cv31 that just installs OpenCV 3.1 and copy inside the executable :

```
FROM debian:jessie
#OpenCV31
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ALL_OPENCV_DEPENDENCIES
RUN CLONE_AND_INSTALL_OPENCV_31
#Executable
COPY my_executable.sh/
ENTRYPOINT ["/my_executable.sh"]
```

Having images in a host folder, I can map this folder inside the container and call the executable on the host like that :

```
docker run -v /host/images:/images i_cv31 /images/image1.jpg /images/image2.jpg /images/result.png
```

The executable writes result.png on the volume, the container ends its task and stops.

Is there a way from the website container to send a signal to the host so that it creates an executable container ? I know we can map the docker.sock from the host to the containers with volumes but somehow I can't make it work and it looks like this is not really secure. As well, it seems the --link of docker run option is deprecated for security reasons, and I don't know how to access files from a container on another one with this option. There seems to be the docker networking option, which, if I understand correctly is what Docker-Compose does.

**To summarize :** My web container writes two images in a volume. This container requires Apache2/Python/Django. The same volume is accessible from another container that launches an executable if we provide it two images. This container requires OpenCV. What I am missing is this signal : The images are ready, launch the executable and give back the result so the website can display it.
Up to now, this signal was an Ajax call in a Javascript file. It sent the two images to Django, which called the executable and knew when the result image was ready so it could be displayed.

I'm really lost so thanks a lot for any help you can give me.

Comment: Mounting docker.sock itself is not insecure itself, as long as your application is not vulnerable. --link is deprecated, because using docker networking does that by default (if you start 2 services with docker-compose they are accessible for each other using service name)

Comment: Mounting docker.sock is *insecure* and an ugly hack that is considered bad practice.  It's only useful to run Docker inside Docker and testing applications that interact with the Docker API for orchestration.  We can never assume that an application is invulnerable.